# Question about an eigenvalue problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a question... How can I show that the eigenvalue problem $$y''+λy=0$$ $$y(0)=0,$$ $$ y'(0)=\frac{y'(1)}{2}$$
is NOT a Sturm-Liouville problem?

Comment: What is your definition of a Sturm-Liouville problem? What you have is exactly the Sturm-Liouville equation, for $p=1$, $q=0$, $w=1$...

Comment: @user7530 $\text{The eigenvalue problem } Ly=(py')'+qy=λy,$ $a \leq x \leq b \text{ is of the form Sturm-Liouville if it satisfies the boundary conditions }$ $p(a)W(u(a),v^*(a))=p(b)W(u(b),v^*(b)). $

Comment: @user7530 So to show that the eigenvalue problem is not a Sturm-Liouville problem do I have to show that the relation does not stand? That means that:
$$p(a)W(u(a),v^*(a))  \neq p(b)W(u(b),v^*(b))$$

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure what W is, though.

Comment: @user7530 $W$ is the Wronskian.

Comment: @user7530 So suppose that $u, v^*$, solutions of the eigenvalue problem $y''+λy=0$, satisfy the boundary conditions, so:
$$u(0)=0, u'(0)=\frac{u'(1)}{2} \text{ and } v^*(0)=0, v^{*'}(0)=\frac{v^{*'}(1)}{2}$$

$$W(u(0),v^*(0))=u(0)v^{*'}(0)-u'(0)v^*(0)=0$$

$$W(u(1),v^*(1))=u(1)v^{*'}(1)-u'(1)v^*(1)=u(1) 2 v^{*'}(0)-2 u'(0)v^*(1)=2(u(1)  v^{*'}(0)- u'(0)v^*(1))$$

So how can I show that this is not equal to $0$?

Comment: @user7530 Or is there an other way to show that this is not a Sturm-Liouville problem?